# Selecting specific rows with Sqldf using where clause in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I have 2 data frames each with 2 columns that is unsorted and i want to get sqldf to print the value of column (Orep) when both rows of df1 matches rows in df2

[image]

This is my starting code that I am still building on. I am stuck on the where clause because it is generating the output i want

```
library(sqldf)     
df1<- data.frame(mydata1)
df2 <- data.frame(mydata2)

con1<- sqldf ("SELECT Orep FROM df2 Where df1.Item=df2.Oitem And df1.Rep=df2.Orep ")
```

it give me zero rows instead of AS-DA.

i get the result i wanted when i used the code below but i need the where clause to work because i have other logical conditions to perform on the query.

```
sqldf('SELECT * FROM df1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM df2')
```

Eventually, I want to run a query that compares both columns of df1 and df2 and return 'match' or 'No Match' or latest (*if df1.item = df2.Oitem And df1.Rep=99-99* ) in a new column, something like this

mydata2
 Oitem -----|----Orep|-- Results
1. BC-GA |    XY-RA  |   No Match
2. CV-DC |    XY-RB  |   No Match
3. CV-DA |    AS-DA  |   Match
4. CV-DD |    AS-DD  |   Latest

[image]

Comment: Please do not provide the input as images. It makes it impossible for others to copy and paste the data.

Comment: This is my first post. I will input it in the correct format next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the first `select` in the question is that it tries to use `df1` even though it is not in the `from` clause.

Now, assume that:

- `Item` is unique in `df1` and `Oitem` is unique in `df2`.  (If not please revise the question to explain how to deal with duplicates.)
- `df1` and `df2` are given as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.
- there should be one output row for each `df2` row.

Then we have:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select 
       df2.*,
       case 
        when Item = OItem and Rep = ORep then 'Match'
        when Item = OItem and Rep = '99-99' then 'Latest'
        else 'Nomatch' 
       end Results
       from df2 left join df1 on Item = Oitem")
```

giving:

```
  Oitem  Orep Results
1 BC-GA XY-RA Nomatch
2 CV-DC XY-RB Nomatch
3 CV-DA AS-DA   Match
4 CV-DD AS-DD  Latest
```

**Note:** `df1` and `df2` in reproducible form are given below. Note that `read.csv` defaults to `header = TRUE`.

```
Lines1 <- "
Item | Rep
CV-DA | AS-DA
CV-DB | AS-DB
CV-DC | AS-DC
CV-DD | 99-99"
df1 <- read.csv(text = Lines1, as.is = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "
Oitem | Orep
BC-GA | XY-RA
CV-DC | XY-RB
CV-DA | AS-DA
CV-DD | AS-DD"
df2 <- read.csv(text = Lines2, as.is = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: it works perfectly and it gives me the same result that my Vlookup produced.

Comment: For the cases that had No Match, I extended the code to replace No Match with the correct Replacement(Rep) . Now i want to take the Orep from Match cases and use it as a new col Oitem_new and compare it with Item from df1. so if item = Oitem_new and Rep = ' ' then 'No new replacement' else if item = oitem_new and Rep != ' ' then Rep. Also can i iterate this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL inner join:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select b.Orep from df1 as a
      inner join df2 as b
        on a.Item = b.Oitem and
           a.Rep = b.Orep")
```

**Result:**

```
   Orep
1 AS-DA
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = read.table(text = "Item|Rep  
1.|CV-DA|AS-DA
2.|CV-DB|AS-DB
3.|CV-DC|AS-DC
4.|CV-DD|99-99", header = TRUE, sep = "|", row.names = 1)

df2 = read.table(text = "Oitem|Orep  
1.|BC-GA|XY-RA
2.|CV-DC|XY-RB
3.|CV-DA|AS-DA
4.|CV-DD|AS-DD", header = TRUE, sep = "|", row.names = 1)
```